# is empty response with status 200 possible via aws serverless?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless

So I want the response body to be empty. I tried varionations of the following:

```
export const hello = async (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, null)
}
```

However this returns a string 'null'.

If I don't invoke the callback lambda responds with a timeout error or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

callback is expecting an HTTP response object in second argument. Try like this.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: '200',
        body: ''
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks! in order for this to work though the endpoint integration should be `lambda-proxy`